# Get IQueryable from Moq mockset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have tried following the [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) using Entity Framework and Moq to mock my context to test my repository.

I'm currently having problems testing my `GetSingle` query from my repository:

```
public Customer GetSingle(int id, HotelBookingContext context = null, params Expression<Func<Customer, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    using (var tempContext = context ?? new HotelBookingContext())
    {
        IQueryable<Customer> dbQuery = tempContext.Set<Customer>();

        foreach (Expression<Func<Customer, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);

        return dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

using the following test:

```
public void GetSingle_QueryingASingleCustomer_ReturnsASingleCustomer()
{
    var cus = new Customer() { Email = "testMail", Name = "testName", Id = 1 };
    var customer = new List<Customer> {cus}.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Customer>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(customer.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(customer.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(customer.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(customer.GetEnumerator());

    var mockContext = new Mock<HotelBookingContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Customers).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var temp = _customerRepository.GetSingle(cus.Id, mockContext.Object);
    Assert.AreEqual(temp.Name, cus.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(temp.Email, cus.Email);
    Assert.AreEqual(temp.Id, cus.Id);
}
```

If I debug the code I notice that in the `GetSingle` function the `IQueryable` called `dbQuery` remains `null` and can therefore not be used in the return statement.

Why is this?

However, if I run it with a real context it works fine.

Comment: That is because in the setup you setup `.Customers` property and not the `.Set<Customer>()` function. Moq has no clue what to do with that based on the current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in the setup you setup `.Customers` property on the mocked context and not the `.Set<Customer>()` function. Moq has no clue what to do with that based on the current setup.

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Customer>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

The above setup should now match the expected behavior of the method under test in its current format.

Other wise if this is the setup...

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Customers).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

...then you need to update the method under test to ...

```
IQueryable<Customer> dbQuery = tempContext.Customers;
```

for the test to exercise as expected.